# How to implement OpAmp floating input protection

Tags: operational-amplifier, pcb, analog

I needed a VCCS so then I simulated the circuit below in LTSpice and it worked great. I also designed the PCB and produced it, solder it and it still works great. But I have a big problem!

When the input (positive input of the opamp) is left unconnected, and the load is connected, the opamp hugs the VPOS or VNEG rails (arbitrarly!) and the output current goes to 2.35A (I am lucky that I put that current limiting resistor so the current will never go above +/- 2.35 ampers.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I think this is because of the input offset voltage of the [MP38](https://www.apexanalog.com/resources/products/mp38u.pdf) and the fact that with no input since it will be open loop...it hugs the supply rail (I do not understand why sometimes it goes to V+ and sometimes goes to V-).

So my questions are:

1. Is what I said above the problem? or there is more to it?
2. How to prevent this kind of behaviour (possibly with some schematics
       please!)
3. What could I do better for this Circuit/PCB?

Would be this a solution (R1, 10k resistor pull-down parallel with input connector):
[image]

Comment: I don't quite get why the + of the opamp would be left unconnected, it seems to have at least a connections to the output side, which bears the other question of why you did it that way and not try to follow the reference schematic of the datasheet

Comment: Add a pull-down resistor in parallel to your input connector. When a source is connected it serves no purpose, when unconnected it biases the input for 0V.

Comment: @sstobbe Doesn't a pull down resistor from input of the connector to ground make a voltage divider and screw the result?

Comment: Not if Ro of your voltage source is low. You can try it in spice add a resistor in parallel to Vin(2)

Comment: @sstobbe Please check the image I added, is this what you mean?

Comment: @Sean87 Exactly, when a source Vin is connected the voltage input is defined exclusively by the input (assuming Ro is low). If Vin is disconnected the input is approximate zero, I would try to use the lowest pull-down resistor you can

Comment: @sstobbe hmm I did with 10k in real thing and it didnt work...I try lower values and report back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the input voltage applied the opamp is **not** in open loop. It still has feedback but the feedback has become **positive** instead of **negative**. I do not think offset has anything to do with this.

All 4 feedback resistors are 10 k so feedback to both inputs (inverting and non-inverting) is 1/2. If you disconnect the input source then the feedback to the non-inverting input changes to 1 so it "wins" when compared to the (still 1/2) feedback of the inverting input.

I disregard the fact that the negative feedback is from one side of the sense resistor and the positive feedback is coming from the other side. But since the voltage across the sense resistor is small I think I can safely do this.

A possible solution might be to apply the input voltage on the inverting input side and **ground** the left side of Rin1. That way when there is no input voltage source applied the negative feedback would increase (which is OK, I think) but the positive feedback stays at 1/2.

You might also have to swap the feedback signals around the sense resistor since you would be introducing the input voltage at the negative side now.

If possible, compare both situations in a simulator and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am having a hard time understanding your possible solution...would it possible to add a schematic to your answer?

Comment: Sorry, too lazy. And the change is **quite simple**, first schematic: move Rin2 **down** to where Vin and Rin1 are. Move Vin and Rin1 **up** to where Rin2 is. If you really need a schematic then **you** draw it, edit your question and use the included schematic drawing tool. Then add a comment here under my answer that you did that (so I will get a notification) then I will come back, copy and change that schematic from your question and include it in my answer.